# Loading rvm environment in restored OS X Terminal windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm

If I quit OS X Terminal when the shell is positioned in an RVM-managed directory (e.g., a Rails app), and then restart Terminal, OS X kindly positions the shell in the directory where it was before. However, rvm does not seem to reset the gemset in use  (e.g. Gemfile:#ruby-gemset).

Is this just me? Have I mucked something up? (Always possible!)

If others have the same issue, has anyone solved it or worked around?

Presently, I do `cd ~; cd -`, and RVM's "cd" implementation sets things up right. But it's kinda annoying. Really, I'd rather Terminal didn't save cwd in the first place; then I'd only need one `cd`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to setup a base gemset in RVM first.

```
rvm gemset create gemsetnamehere
```

If you want to use that gemset as default, you just do like so:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-head@gemsetnamehere --default
```

The assumption in the above is that you're using ruby 1.9.2-head and want the gemset you just created gemsetnamehere as the default. Check the RVM docs here: http://rvm.io/gemsets/using

Also, if you want it just for that directory. Create a .rvmrc file in the project's root and include something like:

```
rvm 1.9.2-head2@gemsetnamehere
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, thanks, but no help at all there: the reason I couched it as "restart Terminal" and "reset gemset" is because I already have all that in place: it works for the basic case (cd into the directory); it only fails during Terminal's "Restore" function. Apparently, Terminal does this by chdir() within Terminal itself, before launching the shell, rather than stuffing a "cd" into the shell's stdin.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry about that. I guess I misunderstood the question. Not sure I have much else for you right now.